# iOS ACAccountStore Code=7, Cannot renew credentials. Unknown client:

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios6

I'm working with the new iOS 6 Facebook API and have generally had a "challenging" time with the ACAccountStore methods.  I retrieve an ACAccount with:

```
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:self.facebookAccountType
                                          options:options completion:^(BOOL granted,     NSError *error) {
```

I then need to periodically renew the ACAccount token with:

```
[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:self.facebookAccountType
                                      options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError     *error) {
```

This works whenever I start from a clean iOS simulator environment using "Reset Contents and Settings.."

But after a while I get the following.

```
Error Domain=com.apple.accounts Code=7 "Cannot renew credentials. Unknown client: FBTest     (org.my.app.FBTest)"
```

I'm executing the call from the FBTest app.

There are a lot of posts on how to get iOS 6 FB up and running and I'm past that point.  The tricky part with the framework is keeping it running over time.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the following :

- Ensure that you are using the very latest accounts framework.
- Give the application its real bundle ID, not "org.my.app.FBTest".
- Make sure the keystore settings is on in the entitlements file.
- Test this on a adhoc distribution build.